# Modify DNS queries for TLD

Tags: bind, internal-dns, tld, windows-dns

There is an issue. They introduced new TLD ".dev" and I have internal zone "dev.companyname.com". Some internal users use short names to access hosts in this zone (i.e. they access hostname.dev instead of full name). Is there any way I can modify DNS queries (on BIND server or Microsoft DNS server) from hostname.dev to hostname.dev.companyname.com (i.e. append companyname.com to every query that ends with .dev)? Or may be there is a way I can reject requests like hostname.dev ? It is required only as a temporary solution - I understand that I have to move all hosts away from this zone.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe configuring a DNS suffix via Windows TCP/IP configuration could be your solution here, providing you're running Windows PC's. This allows you to append the end of a DNS query.

- [Appending DNS Suffix](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc816716(v=ws.10).aspx)
- [Applying via GPO](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/the-enterprise-cloud/manage-dns-suffix-configuration-through-group-policy/)

Another solution is to redirect specific queries using forward look up zones within DNS management on the server, that's if there's not too many sites this problem is affecting.

Oh and make sure users primary DNS is your servers, otherwise it will ignore any changes you make.

Comment: Yes, thanks it works fine on Windows. But on linux clients I still cannot resolve it correctly. Though in the resolve.conf I can see search dev.companyname.com companyname.com